# Environment variables are not being set in npm scripts using cross-env

Tags: vue.js, npm, environment-variables, npm-scripts

I am trying to run `npm run test`, where part of test is setting an environment variable using `cross-env`. However, in Cypress testing the environment variable is not actually changed. Thanks for the help!

I am using Windows, with a `cross-env` version of 5.0.1.

I have tried to set the several environment variable with different combinations, such as SET && and setting it in different places in the command but none have actually changed the environment variable. I also tried installing `better-npm-run` but it did not help solve this problem.

```
I am running npm run test, where in test RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY is an environment variable and start is npm run dev.
test: cross-env RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY='6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI' start-server-and-test start  http-get://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Instead of the recaptcha key changing, the original site key is being used instead.

Comment: Could you include a snippet with your actual npm script? I'm not sure what `test: cross-env RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY...` is, it looks like pseudocode. Good tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: @WillCain done, I am using npm run test, where test is equal to the script above.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. That snippet is from `package.json`? That doesn't look like JSON. I wonder if it's a syntax problem? Should look something like `{ "scripts" : { "test" : "cross-env RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY..." ... } ... }`.